# How to hover two elements implicitly while hovering another one with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

is there a way to trigger the hover of two elements when hovering on another one with JQuery?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript.js'></script>
          <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class='hidden'></div>
       <div class='triggerOtherHover' onmouseover='hoverImplicitly();'></div>
       <div class='hidden'></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my style.css:

```
.hidden { 
          background-color:red;
          border: 1px solid black;
          opacity:0;
          transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
          width: 100px;
          height:100px;
 }
.hidden:hover, .visible {
          opacity:1;
}

.triggerOtherHover {
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           background-color:green;
}
```

Here is my javascript.js:

```
function hoverImplicitly {
           $(".hidden").toggleClass('visible');
}
```

When I hover the mouse on the **div.triggerOtherHover**, the other two divs with .hidden class become red cause of the opacity, but when I remove the mouse from the div.triggeOtherHover, the divs are still red. I would like them to become transparent (opacity: 0) again.
Is there a way to make them behave like the CSS :hover pseudo class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `mouseout` handler to the div as well, so that the class gets removed when focused out of it.

```
   <div class="triggerOtherHover" onmouseover="hoverImplicitly();" onmouseout="hoverImplicitly();">
```

Or instead of adding inline handler bind the event to the element using `hover` pseudoevent.

```
 $(function(){
    $('.triggerOtherHover').hover(hoverImplicitly); //hover represent mouseenter, mouseleave
});
```

Also note that you are missing parens `()` in the function declaration `function hoverImplicitly()`

Comment: Yes I forgot the parens while writing the example of the function.

So if I use the second way, where should I put the `$(function(){
    $('.triggerOtherHover').hover(hoverImplicitly); //hover represent mouseenter, mouseleave
});` ? Sorry but I am a newbie of JQuery.

Comment: @user3019105 You can put it in the `head` or `body` inside a script tag. `<script>$(function(){ $('.triggerOtherHover').hover(hoverImplicitly);</script>`

Comment: I put it in the javascript.js file after the function hoverImplicitly() definition, but it didn't work. Where's the problem?

Comment: @user3019105 you might be missing closing braces.. See this demo http://jsbin.com/oxuPamAp/1/edit It should be `$(function(){$('.triggerOtherHover').hover(hoverImplicitly);});`

Comment: @user3019105 You are welcome. If it helped do you mind marking as answer?

Comment: Sure! Sorry! I forgot it!